aws s3 sync not excluding file with certain extension
I have the following aws s3 sync command:
sudo aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket/my-root-folder /home/output-dir --delete --include "*" --exclude "*.zip"

I'm expecting this command to download all the files in s3://my-bucket/my-root-folder to /home/output-dir EXCEPT for any .zip files and remove any .zip files that already exist in output-dir.
However when I run find ~/output-dir -type f -name "*.zip" I am still seeing zip files
I've also tried
sudo aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket/my-root-folder /home/output-dir --delete --include "*" --exclude "\*.zip"

and
sudo aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket/my-root-folder /home/output-dir --delete --exclude "\*.zip"

and in both cases zip files is still included.

Turned out it was an issue with running the above command in a python subprocess. after seeing this answer in another so article I was able to fix this error by stripping the double quote from my command.
